# Goal: Read two strings in, break apart csv and compare values in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to figure this out, but its already been a week. Anyone have advice on how to proceed?

I want to:
foreach entry in splitOne (a comma separated string of any length), compare with each splitTwo (a comma separated string of any length). If there's a match, show the node. If not, don't.

If this was C#, this would be over already. But in XSLT1.0 (and ONLY XSLT 1.0), this is a big problem for me.

splitOne is the OUTER LOOP and splitTwo is the INNERLOOP.

I'm open to other ways than XSLT to do this, but the end product must be XML.

--blue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
                extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
                version="1.0" >

  <xsl:param name="Groups_From_Logged_In_User"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <application>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </application>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Module">
    <Module>
      <xsl:attribute name="Control">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Control"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Program"/>
    </Module>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Program">

    <xsl:call-template name="split">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="@assocGroups"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="splitTwo">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$Groups_From_Logged_In_User"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <!-- foreach splitOne, compare with each splitTwo. If there's a match, show the node. If not, don't.-->


    <Program>
      <xsl:attribute name="Control">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Control"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Value">
        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="assocGroups">
        <xsl:value-of select="@assocGroups"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </Program>
    <!-- </xsl:if> -->
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="split">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>
    <xsl:variable name="separator">,</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($pText) = 0"/>
      <xsl:when test="contains($pText, $separator)">
        <splitOne>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $separator)"/>
        </splitOne>
        <xsl:call-template name="split">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, $separator)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <splitOne>
          <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
        </splitOne>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="splitTwo">
    <xsl:param name="pText"/>
    <xsl:variable name="separator">,</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($pText) = 0"/>
      <xsl:when test="contains($pText, $separator)">
        <splitTwo>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, $separator)"/>
        </splitTwo>
        <xsl:call-template name="splitTwo">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, $separator)"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <splitTwo>
          <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
        </splitTwo>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the XML I am running this against.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<application name="Home">
<Module Control="PayStation Setup">
    <Program Control="PSF0010 Facility Group Codes" Value="PSF0010 Facility Group Codes" assocGroups="1,2,3" />
    <Program Control="PSF0015 Facility Reps" Value="PSF0015 Facility Reps" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0016 Facility Gasoline" Value="PSF0016 Facility Gasoline" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0017 Facility Warranty" Value="PSF0017 Facility Warranty" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0020 Facility Codes" Value="PSF0020 Facility Codes" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0021 Facility Codes Inquiry" Value="PSF0021 Facility Codes Inquiry" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0023 Facility VDN" Value="PSF0023 Facility VDN" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0025 AAR Facilities" Value="PSF0025 Facility Facilities" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0030 Club Codes" Value="PSF0030 Club Codes" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0040 Additional Services" Value="PSF0040 Additional Services" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0050 Additional Services Detail" Value="PSF0050 Additional Services Detail" assocGroups="1,2" />
    <Program Control="PSF0060 Start Miles (OM)" Value="PSF0060 Start Miles (OM)" assocGroups="1,2" />

  </Module>
</application>
```

I only need the Program nodes above where a value in assocGroup is also in $Groups_From_Logged_In_User

Comment: We need to see the XML you're running this against, plus the XML you expect to have output.

Comment: The output XML is the same as the one above, but the Program node is removed if the value from the first CSV is not also in the second CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do an identity transform and only handle the `<Program>` element specially. I'd recursively split off the first CSV and see whether it appears in the `assocGroups` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="Groups_From_Logged_In_User"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Program">
    <!-- We have to append a ',' to $Groups_From_Logged_In_User so that we still get 
         something back from substring-before(...,',') in the last iteration -->
    <xsl:param name="list" select="concat($Groups_From_Logged_In_User,',')"/>
    <!-- We also add commas around @assocGroups because we want to check for appearances of ",1," 
         rather than "1", as this would also be found in "11", which is not what we want to find -->
    <xsl:param name="assocGroups" select="concat(',',@assocGroups,',')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- We we've chipped everything off the list, we quit -->
      <xsl:when test="$list=''"/>
      <!-- Now we chip off the first bit of the list, wrap it in commas and see whether it appears in $asscoGroups -->
      <xsl:when test="contains($assocGroups,concat(',',substring-before($list,','),','))">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- If we didn't find anything, we drop the first value and recurse. -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
          <xsl:with-param name="list" select="substring-after($list,',')"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="assocGroups" select="$assocGroups"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thomas W,Thanks for your Educational and Complete Answer.